# HighCharts: Highlight a specific value with a different coloured marker

Tags: highcharts

I have to create a line graph with Highcharts and the colour of the marker should vary according to a particular value. 
Example - My data is like:

```
 {
    "date": "2017-01-01",
    "cost": 5,
    "value": 1
  }
```

The graph is plotted with ***cost vs date***. If the ***value*** is **1** it should be red and if the ***value*** if **0** the colour should be blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your data to the format required by Highcharts and set the marker color:

```
var data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-01",
    "cost": 5,
    "value": 1
}, {
    "date": "2017-01-02",
    "cost": 5,
    "value": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-01-03",
    "cost": 5,
    "value": 1
}].map(obj => {
    return {
        name: obj.date,
        y: obj.cost,
        marker: {
            fillColor: obj.value ? 'red' : 'blue'
        }
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/btkuwL21/